# stop converting string to number, performing mathematical operation

Tags: java, jsp

I have an `ArrayList<String>` that I am passing from servlet to JSP as a request attribute. The strings are in the form of `01-00111`. So, I am doing

```
<%java.util.ArrayList<String> selectedProjects=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("relProjects");%>
var selProjects = <%=selectedProjects%>;
console.log(selProjects);
```

I want it to be logged in the console as:

```
01-00111  
01-00112
```

Instead, it gets printed as:

```
-00110  
-00111
```

How do I stop javascript from assuming these strings to be numbered and performing subtraction on them?

Comment: That's java, not javascript.

Comment: @Geuis it's about what their javascript is doing, generated by java with jsp.

Comment: Can you show the actual javascript that gets generated into your page source, so that we (but really, you) can check whether this is the Java side, or the JS side, doing the wrong thing?

Comment: My question would be how the leading zeroes are being kept if there really was subtraction. Also numbers with leading zeroes only work on non-strict and are legacy octals. I somehow doubt there is really subtraction going on, javascript side.

Comment: Have you tried adding some `"` quotes to the string?

Comment: sorry about the leading zeroes. that was my mistake.

Comment: From page source, var selectedProjects = [04-00593, 05-10120]; But what gets printed in the console are -589, -10115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your value in quotes in JavaScript. It will be treated as a string, not a number:

```
var selProjects = "<%=selectedProjects%>";
```